How do I reference a column of a database inside a Function?
Im trying to create a function to short my code.
I need to create percentiles of a multiple set of variables/columns that are inside my database:
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE FUNCTION
    My_Project.Create_Percentiles(var_cotas ANY TYPE)
AS (
    select percentiles[offset(20)] as p20
         , percentiles[offset(40)] as p40
         , percentiles[offset(60)] as p60
         , percentiles[offset(80)] as p80
    from (  select approx_quantiles(var_cotas, 100) percentiles
            from 
                 (select var_cotas as variavel
                  FROM Project.My_Project.Estuda_Inadimplencia
                  where data_version = '2023-01-01')));

SELECT * FROM `Project.My_Project.Create_Percentiles`(min_u2safr_score);


The return is: Unrecognized name: min_u2safr_score
I guess my error is to reference a column (min_u2safr_score) that is inside my database (Estuda_Inadimplencia) and not a value itself. Is there a way to do that?
I already tried to:

Call the function as SELECT * FROM Project.My_Project.Create_Percentiles("min_u2safr_score");
Inserted the parameter RETURN TABLE p20 numeric, p40 numeric, p60 numeric, p80 numeric
Tried to change the first line to: (var_cotas Integer) / (var_cotas Numeric) / (var_cotas Float64) / (var_cotas Int64)
Changed the sintaxe to {var_cotas}.

Nothing worked.

You are renaming your input var_cotas as variavel in your innermost subquery.  Either remove as variavel or use approx_quantiles(variavel, 100) in the outer subquery.
